# Write a function sumRange, which, when given two integers FROM and TO, returns the sum of integers from FROM to TO

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please tell me how I could write this code better, I'm having a bit of trouble getting mine to work

```
function sumRange(from, to) {
      var f = from;
      var t = to;
      var result = from;
      if(to >= from) {
        while (to > from) {
          from ++;
          result += from;
        }
        return result;
      } else if (from > to) {
        result = to;
        while (from > to ) {
          to++;
          result += to;
        }
        return result;
      }

    }
```

Comment: `having a bit of trouble` How? Works for me

Comment: `write this code better` if it doesn't work, then better would be to make it work. If it does work, then this isn't the place to ask :p

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the integers between `a` and `b` is:

```
((b - a + 1) * (a + b)) / 2
```

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html

To handle the arguments in any order:

```
function sumRange(a, b) {
    return ((Math.abs(b - a) + 1) * (a + b)) / 2;
}
```